# Error en funcion para sumar datos tipo TIME

Tags: php, datetime, time

tengo el siguiente problema con una función que utilizo para sumar dos horas, una de las horas viene de una consulta, la cual es un campo tipo TIME y la otra hora es la que mando por un POST. Lo que quiero es sumarle a la hora que me trajo la consulta las horas que llegan por POST, para ir guardando la cantidad de horas trabajadas en la semana:

Ej:

Horas que imprime la consulta 16:00:00

Horas que llegan por POST para sumarselas al campo de la tabla: 07:59:00

Resultado: 23:59:00

Ahora el problema esta cuando el resultado pasa a 24:00:00, ejemplo:

Hora 1: 16:00:00

Hora 2: 08:00:00

El resultado debería ser `24:00:00` pero lo que muestra es `00:00:00`

La función es la siguiente:

```
function SumaHoras($hora1,$hora2){
  $a = new DateTime($hora1);
  $b = new DateInterval((new DateTime($hora2))->format('\P\TH\Hi\Ms\S')); 
  $a->add($b); //Sumo las horas
  return $a->format('H:i:s'); //Imprimo las horas
}
```

Noto que el problema esta cuando la hora se pasa de 23:59:59 que es cuando llega a 24.

Lo que se me ocurre es que esta tomando como máximo a 24 horas creo que por el format que le doy en el return.

Pero no consigo la manera de solucionarlo, agradecería mucho una ayuda.

Comment: Si quieres guardar un número de horas no debes darle formato DateTime(), ya que le da el formato de 24H y no te dejará continuar sumando, se reiniciará como lo haría un reloj. Puedes guardar las horas como un String o como un Double para guardar también los minutos.

Comment: Si ya note el problema, he cambiado la función y ahora guardo los segundos totales. Gracias

Answer (score 2):

Si quieres guardar un número de horas no debes darle formato DateTime(), ya que le da el formato de 24H y no te dejará continuar sumando, se reiniciará como lo haría un reloj. Puedes guardar las horas como un String, o guardar el total de segundos. Un saludo.